Van Douwen's construction of a strongly connected space
According to this answer by Brian Scott, in the paper A regular space on which every continuous real-valued function is constant by van Douwen there is a method of constructing from any $T_3$ space that's not functionally Hausdorff a space which is $T_3$ and strongly connected.
However Scott's answer seems to be incomplete, because of reasons I've already tried to address in the comments.
I am interested how construction of van Douwen looks like, but the paper is unavailable anywhere online. That's why I would like someone to present me this construction.

the 1972 issue of "Nieuw Archive voor Wiskunde" is not online because of copyright restrictions, but many libraries have it; see https://search.worldcat.org/formats-editions/1760346

The space starts with a regular space $X$ with a pair of twins, $a$ and $b$, say. In the set $X\times X$ we have the two vertical lines $V_a=\{a\}\times X$ and $V_b=\{b\}\times X$. Take a bijection $f:V_a\to(X\times X)\setminus(V_a\cup V_b)$ (note that $X$ has to be infinite).
Now topologize $X\times X$ so that it becomes the direct sum of the horizontal lines $X\times \{x\}$, where each such line is just a copy of the space $X$; abbreviate the horizontal $X\times\{x\}$ by $H_x$.
(Alternatively: take the product topology and enlarge it by declaring each horizontal line to be open.)
The example, $Y$, is the quotient of $X\times X$ determined by the decomposition consisting of $V_b$ and all two-point sets $\{(a,x),f(a,x)\}$, let's abbreviate the latter by $d_x$. Let $q$ be the quotient map. If $g:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then so is $g\circ q$, which is constant on $V_b$, hence on $V_a$, and hence on $X\times X$. It follows that $g$ is constant.
Proving regularity of $Y$ takes a bit more work but it is quite elementary.
The paper is the second one in his Collected Papers
Addendum (2024-12-24): the proof of regularity shows that if $D$ is a member of the decomposition and $U$ is open and saturated with $D\subset U$ then there are saturated open and closed sets $V$ and $F$, respectively with $D\subset V\subset F\subset U$. A set is saturated if it is a union of a subfamily of the decomposition.
Let $D$ be a member of the decomposition and let $U$ be saturated and open with $D\subset U$. If $D=V_b$ then $D$ hits every horizontal line $H_x$ in exactly one point (to wit $(b,x)$), and if $D=d_x$ for some $x$ then it either hits two lines in one point each, or just one line in two points. Choose for every $x$ an open subset $C_x$ of $H_x$ such that:

$C_x=\emptyset$ if $D\cap H_x=\emptyset$;
$D\cap H_x\subset C_x\subset \overline{C}_x\subset U\cap H_x$ if $D$ intersects $H_x$; and
if $D\neq V_b$ then $(b,x)\notin \overline{C}_x$ and if $(a,x)\notin D$ then $(a,x)\notin\overline{C}_x$.

Furthermore choose for every $x$ such that $(a,x)\in U$ an open subset $O_x$ of $H_x$ such that $(a,x)\in O_x\subset\overline{O}_x\subset U$, and $\overline{O}_x\cap V_b=\emptyset$.
Start with $V_1=\bigcup_x C_x$ and $F_1=\bigcup_x\overline{C}_x$.
Then recursively set
$$
V_{n+1}=V_n\cup\bigcup\{O_x:f(a,x)\in V_n\}
$$
and
$$
F_{n+1}=F_n\cup\bigcup\{\overline{O}_x:f(a,x)\in F_n\}
$$
This clearly makes two saturated sets: $V=\bigcup_nV_n$ and $F=\bigcup_nF_n$.
The intersections of $V$ and $F$ with a horizontal line $H_x$ consist of

$C_x$ and $\overline{C}_x$ respectively if $D$ intersects $H_x$; and
the empty set or $O_x$ and $\overline{O}_x$ respectively.
In all cases we have $V\cap H_x\subseteq F\cap H_x\subseteq U\cap H_x$, which guarantees that $V\subseteq F\subseteq U$, and that $V$ is open and $F$ is closed. Furthermore $D\subset V_1\subset V$.


This looks to be pretty much the same thing as what Brian Scott wrote in his answer. But my issue with that answer was precisely the proof of regularity, so while it confirms that the construction is correct, I still have no proof of it being regular

Brian's write-up uses a lot of notation. I'll add a short version to the solution.
